# CiviCRM won't install (blank screen on initial configuration, GoDaddy shared hosting)

Tags: wordpress

I successfully installed CiviCRM using FTP on the backend of my wordpress site hosted by godaddy. when I go to click on configure CiviCRM the next screen comes up blank[image: what I see]

What am I doing wrong? I did install Charity theme from ThemeForest. But I went in and deactivated all of the plugins...

Comment: Can you confirm that you have gone through all the installation steps as described in this document https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/wordpress/ .  Also have you enabled the plug-in and run the installer?

Comment: Yes, I have. I am attempting to start from scratch today,

Answer (score 2):

Unless something has changed, I have never been able to get Civi to work properly on cheaper shared hosting like GoDaddy. Just not enough resources and such given to each account.

Comment: What host client would you recommend?

Comment: I always recommend going with someone who at a minimum has a VPS setup (sometimes called a cloud server) that you can use. One where you can upgrade memory, storage, etc as needed. I use Liquid Web, but there are a number of them out there. You want one where you can set an appropriate amount of resources, like memory, script execution time, etc. I run so many Drupal/Civi sites that we finally just went with a full server so that we could cut it into chunks and resell specifically for Drupal/Civi. You'll probably find a number of places like that as well.

Comment: Sadly my client is locked in with GoDaddy I may need to use salesforce.

Comment: That's too bad, as they'll end up paying a lot for an external CRM like that. Not to mention that eventually they'll also notice issues with their CRM as well when it needs more resources than GoDaddy will give.

Comment: Cheap shared hosting can be expensive, especially if it means you don't have the flexibility to pick the best tools for your organisation. I've seen orgs spend thousands on that mistake. The "lock in" is probably not as bad as you expect (often it's simply that someone with a credit card made a poor decision before consulting experts). If you're truly stuck with GoDaddy, [they do offer a VPS service](https://godaddy.com/hosting/vps-hosting).

Answer (score 0):

Ill always take an opportunity to say **CiviCRM can and will work just fine with shared hosts!** However not all shared hosts are created equal. Two that support CiviCRM requirements include:

- CiviHosting - Supporting Partner of CiviCRM

Each of these hosts have met my needs on a variety of sites. GoDaddy I believe uses CPanel - in CPanel - choose "Select PHP Version" - make sure the right version of PHP is selected (should be 7.1), if not, make sure you select the correct version as current.  Then make sure all the options needed are selected. Finally switch to php options and make sure all those settings are correct too. 
The requirements for CiviCRM can be found here:

https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/requirements/

I should add, shared hosting does have its limits - depending on your needs, your organization may need something more substantial

**Updated 03/22/2019**: Removed TMDhosting as they are no longer a supporting partner, removed stablehost, as I can no longer recommend their services. Removed NameCheap - does not fully support CiviCRM - ran into a lot of issues.

Comment: While CiviCRM may run on shared hosts, I'd advise organisations (whether social change org, business or other) to consider carefully the security of personal contact data in any selected hosting environment. Evaluate your hosting environment against your organisation's data security policies. (If you don't have a data security policy, first check whether you should be collecting personal data.)

Comment: A large number of organizations that use CiviCRM are small.  A VPS is not an option for them for a variety of reasons - technical, budget, etc. Now when selecting a shared host (or any host), you should review their privacy policies, terms of service, and their track record. Both shared and VPS hosting are subject to vulnerabilities and I would argue 
 - if you are not a trained professional, a proper shared host will be more secure than a poorly implemented VPS. However, if security is that much of a a concern - you shouldn't be using a VPS or a Shared Host but rather a dedicated server.

Comment: I think we are on the same page  It's important for organisations to take their custodial role seriously when trusted with personal data.